# What is the most economical way to file a US patent

Tags: filing

I have a product that I am confident will be granted a patent. I am also confident that it is worth patenting from a commercial point of view.
Whilst being very different and not obvious, the product is an improvement on a previous lapsed patent that carries out a repair in domestic homes.
I would like to outline and file my patent application, then launch the product, and complete the patent process with a relevant patent lawyer, whilst the product is selling.
The question I would like to ask is; what is the best and most economical way of achieving this?

Comment: The original question was regarding a world-wide patent. Wile there is no such thing as a WW patent there is an almost WW patent * application* process. It is called a PCT application. To actually eventually get coverage in each country will be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

My overly-simplified view. There are two broad ways to file a utility patent application (I do not know what the title "WW patent" means). Option (a): file the application through a professional (patent lawyer or agent); the "best" option but not the cheapest. Option (b): file it yourself; NOT the "best" but it will the cheapest and will also be unlikely to result in the protection you want.

There are two applications paths available, regardless of the options above. A "Provisional" application will establish your priority date (giving you a year to get things together, incorporation, funding, etc); or a "Non-Provisional" application will begin the actual patent process. If using a Provisional, be aware that your final Non-Provisional will only get the benefit of the earlier 
filing date of the provisional application for content that was well covered in the Provisional. Thus the effort and cost of a really solid Provisional application could be almost equal to the filing of a Non-Provisional application. I have observed that Provisional applications are often used to spawn a series of similar/related Non-Provisional applications, thereby providing a wider range of claims that may collectively provide greater protection to the inventor (or, an wider net for patent trolls to cast).